# AWS GameLift ThrottlingException: Rate exceeded when attempting to retrieve multiple PlayerSessions via JS SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve ALL the data on all the Fleets in our GameLift, to be displayed on a React-powered CMS site.

Currently our page retrieves the Fleets (via `listFleets`), the Fleet Attributes (via `describeFleetAttributes`), and Game Sessions (via `describeGameSessions`).

Here's the code for all of that:

```
requestGameLiftData = async () => {
    const gamelift = new AWS.GameLift();
    try {
        const { FleetIds } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Get Fleet IDs
            gamelift.listFleets({}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) { reject("Fleet id error"); } 
                else { resolve(data); }
            });
        });

        const { FleetAttributes } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Get Fleet Attributes by IDs
            gamelift.describeFleetAttributes(
                { FleetIds: FleetIds },
                function(err, data) {
                    if (err) { reject("Fleet attributes error"); } 
                    else { resolve(data); }
                }
            );
        });

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Save Fleet Attributes to state
            this.setState(
                { fleetList: [...FleetAttributes] },
                () => { resolve(); }
            );
        });

        const instancePromiseArr = [];
        const gameSessionPromiseArr = [];
        const playerSessionPromiseArr = [];
        const { fleetList } = this.state;
        for (let fleet of fleetList) {
            instancePromiseArr.push(this.getFleetInstances(fleet, gamelift));
            gameSessionPromiseArr.push(this.getFleetGameSessions(fleet, gamelift));
        }

        let instanceData; // Get all Instances of every Fleet
        try { instanceData = await Promise.all(instancePromiseArr); }
        catch (err) { throw new Error("Fleet instances error"); }

        let gameSessionData; // Get all Game Sessions of every Fleet
        try { gameSessionData = await Promise.all(gameSessionPromiseArr); }
        catch (err) { throw new Error("Fleet game session error"); }

        fleetList.forEach((fleet, index) => { // Nesting game sessions and instances inside their respective fleets
            fleet["Instances"] = instanceData[index].Instances;
            fleet["GameSessions"] = gameSessionData[index].GameSessions;        
        });
  
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.setState(
                { fleetList: [...fleetList] },
                () => { resolve(); }
            );
        });

        this.setState({isFetched: true});
    } catch (error) { this.setState({isFetched: true}); }
};

getFleetInstances = (fleet, gamelift) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gamelift.describeInstances(
            { FleetId: fleet.FleetId },
            function(err, data) {
                if (err) { reject("Fleet instances error"); } 
                else { resolve(data); }
            }
        );
    });
};

getFleetGameSessions = (fleet, gamelift) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gamelift.describeGameSessions(
            { FleetId: fleet.FleetId },
            function(err, data) {
                if (err) { reject("Fleet game sessions error"); } 
                else { resolve(data); }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Now I have to get the Player Sessions. To that end, I added the following:

```
let playerSessionData; // Before the "Nesting"
try { playerSessionData = await Promise.all(playerSessionPromiseArr); }
catch (err) { throw new Error("Player session error"); }

getPlayersInSession = (gameSession, gamelift) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Function to get Player sessions, outside of requestGameLiftData 
          gamelift.describePlayerSessions(
              { GameSessionId: gameSession.GameSessionId },
              function(err, data) {
                  if (err) { reject("Fleet player sessions error"); } 
                  else { resolve(data); }
              }
          );
    });
};
```

And then modified the `Get all Game Sessions` portion to the following:

```
try {
    gameSessionData = await Promise.all(gameSessionPromiseArr);
    for (const gameSessionItem of gameSessionData) {
        for (const data of gameSessionItem.GameSessions) {
            playerSessionPromiseArr.push(this.getPlayersInSession(data, gamelift, delay));
        }
    }
} catch (err) { throw new Error("Fleet game session error"); }
```

And nested it in:

```
fleetList.forEach((fleet, index) => { // Nesting game sessions and instances inside their respective fleets
    fleet["Instances"] = instanceData[index].Instances;    
    for (const gameSession of gameSessionData[index].GameSessions) {
        gameSession['PlayerSessions'] = [];
        for (const playerSessions of playerSessionData) {
            if (playerSessions.PlayerSessions.length > 0) {
                for (const playerSessionItem of playerSessions.PlayerSessions) {
                    if (playerSessionItem.GameSessionId === gameSession.GameSessionId) {
                      gameSession['PlayerSessions'].push(playerSessionItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    fleet["GameSessions"] = gameSessionData[index].GameSessions;        
});
```

This works... sometimes. Most of the times, I get a `ThrottlingException: Rate exceeded` and `400 Bad Request`. This doesn't happen in other regions with significantly less fleets, so I thought it was related to the sheer number of requests made at once (as of this writing, 8 for the fleets, 8 for GameSessions, and no less than 28 for the PlayerSessions). So I tried adding a delay:

```
for (const gameSessionItem of gameSessionData) {
    let delay = 0;
    for (const data of gameSessionItem.GameSessions) {
        delay += 50;
        playerSessionPromiseArr.push(this.getPlayersInSession(data, gamelift, delay));
    }
}

getPlayersInSession = (gameSession, gamelift, delay) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay)).then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gamelift.describePlayerSessions(
                { GameSessionId: gameSession.GameSessionId},
                function(err, data) {
                    if (err) { reject("Fleet player sessions error"); }
                    else { resolve(data); }
                }
            );
        });
    });
};
```

Which didn't work, of course. Is there anything I'm missing? Or is there another approach to this, to get all the data in one sitting without making too many requests?